# can't display a product with springboot web app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm creating a web app with spring starter, I created a databse with mysql, All I want to do is display a product :
Here is the code :

CatServiceApplication.java :

```java
package org.sid.catservice;

import org.sid.catservice.dao.ProduitRepository;
import org.sid.catservice.entities.Produit;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CatServiceApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private ProduitRepository produitRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CatServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        produitRepository.save(new Produit(null,"Ordinateur Lx45",6700,3));
        produitRepository.save(new Produit(null,"Imprimante HP",1700,3));
        produitRepository.save(new Produit(null,"Smartphone Samsung S9",8000,13));
        
        produitRepository.findAll().forEach(p->{
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        });
        
    }
}
```

Produit.java

```java
package org.sid.catservice.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Produit implements Serializable {
    
    public Produit(Long id, String designation, double price, int quantite) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantite = quantite;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Produit [id=" + id + ", designation=" + designation + ", price=" + price + ", quantite=" + quantite
                + "]";
    }
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String  designation;
    private double price;
    private int quantite;
}
```

ProduitRepository

```java
package org.sid.catservice.dao;

import org.sid.catservice.entities.Produit;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ProduitRepository extends JpaRepository<Produit, Long>{

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prod-catal?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
#spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

And here is the output :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:794) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.sid.catservice.CatServiceApplication.main(CatServiceApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : org.sid.catservice.entities.Produit; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : org.sid.catservice.entities.Produit
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.sid.catservice.CatServiceApplication.run(CatServiceApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:791) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : org.sid.catservice.entities.Produit
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:705) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5204) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1598) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1755) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1616) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:396) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

[2m2021-07-03 12:18:19.082[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32024[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2021-07-03 12:18:19.086[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32024[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2021-07-03 12:18:19.105[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32024[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 -
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is telling you that you need a default constructor in your `Produit` entity. You have defined your own constructor along with lombok annotations. Same for the `ToString()` method, you have defined it, but also used the Lombok `@ToString` annotation. Choose one way but don't use both.

Comment: @Yann39 thank you for your answer , So if I delete the Lombok annotation it will work ? I will test it now

Comment: @Yann39 Unfortunately even I removed the annotations but it still does not work

Comment: You need a default constructor, which means a constructor without any argument, this is needed because Hibernate uses the default constructor method to create a bean class using reflections. So remove your constructor and the `toString()` method from your class content, keep only required `@Entity` and `@NoArgsConstructor` annotations and it should work.

Comment: I did what you told me to do and now I'm getting this error in CatServiceApplication.java :                                       
the method save(s) in the type crudrepository is not applicable for the arguments , any idea ?

Comment: Oh don't saw you use the all args constructor, so of course if you need it also keep `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation. Note that this is not really recommended to use Lombok along with JPA unless you are aware about common pitfalls. Also if you don't use `@Data` anymore you may want to add `@EqualsAndHashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says

> No default constructor for entity

Just use Lombok annotations:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
```

Or add 2 constructors manually
In IDEA you could:

1. Press ctrl + N
2. Constructor